# Set flex application size

Tags: apache-flex, size

I have set the size of the application container 
width="1040" height="716"

When I run the application, I get a clipped version of the application. I am using a 1024 X 768 monitor. I understand that the size of the application is greater than than of the available browser space, so where do I set the application to have scroll to show the full application.

Methods tried:

1. Set scroll policy for application container (will not work because the browser needs to have scrolls not application)
2. Set scroll="yes" in body tag of the wrapper html.
3. Set size in the width and height of the flashvars of the wrapper html.

Nothing has resolved the issue yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code of the HTML wrapper and the MXML?

Comment: I had changed the code of the HTML wrapper but changed that back, it is the default wrapper created by flex builder. This is the application tag.
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
 width="1040" height="716"
 backgroundGradientColors="[16777215,16777215]"
 creationComplete="init()"
 verticalScrollPolicy="auto" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
 paddingBottom="8" paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8" paddingTop="8"
 horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in the html wrapper being generated.
The html had a line
body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }

this was clipping the content.
I changed it to
body { margin: 0px; overflow:auto }

Thanks for all your help

Comment: If you found the solution, mark it as the answer, so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

in the head of you mxml add

verticalScrollPolicy="auto" (use autocomplete to get the exact words)
same for 
horizonatalScrollPolicy

This decides if an application is allowed to show scroll bars.

Comment: I have already done that but that does not give me scroll bars

Answer (score 0):

But that's not user-friendly. Normally, you should avoid horzontal scrolling at any cost (vertical scrolling is fine). How often do you still see web pages with horizontal scrolling?

Can you not adjust the layout so that it fits horizontally, designed for 1024 X 768? If it doesn't fit horizontally, adjust it so that it extends vertically.

Comment: You are correct but that's a layout decided by the users and we have to cater to that.